# Need some information about income on application

Tags: visas, uk

I need some information and help on this matter.

For example, as per income tax return yearly income is PKR 8.4 million, which is monthly PKR 700,000. But every month I can't transfer this much amount to my personal bank account. Because this money is used in my business bank account for more investment.

I just transferred PKR 300,000 to my personal bank account every month for my exclusive use. Now, which income should I put in the UK visa form? While applying for a UK visit visa, is it fine to show a monthly income lower than the income stated in the tax returns documents?

Answer (score 2):

If you are submitting tax returns, then your income should show what is shown in the tax documents.

Clearly, there is some other official statement indicating your position and salary; submit this document as well.

Now, which account it goes to and how you distribute funds is your business. You need to show a clear path from:

```
[a] income you state
 v
[b] proof of legitimate income
 v 
[c] proof that you have access to this income and
 v
[d] that the costs of the trip are not a financial burden on you
```

I hope this clarifies the matter.

Don't ... I repeat ... don't .... borrow money or pad your account to show a specific balance. Doing so will almost guarantee your application getting rejected due to deceit or fraud.

This practice of padding accounts to show a balance is called funds parking.

Comment: thanks your answer. I am proprietor of my company. There is no salary. If I mention my tax return's income then I couldn't demonstrate this income at bank statement. Because I told in my question that I just transferred 300000 to my personal account for living expenses. Tax return's income generating after tax paid. That much income not possible to transfer in personal account every month. Hope you understand now

Comment: @Abid If you are the proprietor of the business, you should show the drawings that you take from the company, and support this with the P&L for the business demonstrating the profits it’s making (from which you derive your income).

Comment: @Traveller yes I will show drawings from the company account with proof. Its mean I should state my income tax return's income and brief them in cover letter I draw from my business for living expense.

Comment: Get your company lawyer to write a letter "To Whom It May Concern" stating your position in the company, the remuneration you take. If possible have your accountant or financial auditor write a letter stating a financial summary of your company, including your earnings (payout) over the last few months (or the last fiscal reporting cycle, if you have one).